# how to converting pixel coordinates x and y of an image to an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates, pixel

I have a set of vectors x and y which contains the pixel coordinates of an image. And i need to convert those values to an image using Matlab. How can I use these values? Αnd which function is best suitable for it? The code i used is:

```
I = imread('D:\majorproject\image\characters\ee.jpg');

imshow(I)

BW =im2bw(I);

BW=imcomplement(BW);

imshow(BW)

dim = size(BW);

col = round(dim(2)/2)-90;

row = find(BW(:,col), 1 );

boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row, col],'N');

imshow(I)

hold on;

plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'0','LineWidth',3);

BW_filled = imfill(BW,'holes');

boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_filled);

for k=1:10

   b = boundaries{k};

   plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'g','LineWidth',3);
end
```

from which i got the coordinate values.
Thank you.

Comment: To form an image you generally need an array of intensity values, and the dimensions of the image in pixels (height and width). You say you have only the 'coordinates'... This doesn't make sense by itself.
Could you elaborate? Please state the size of your arrays as it may help, as well as the dimensions that it should appear as, if you know it.

Comment: hi, I dont heve the intensity values for that iamge. and need the image in binary format. thank you

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using loops and consider using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to index into your output image instead.  `sub2ind` will convert `(x,y)` coordinates into linear indices so that you can index what you want using a single command:

```
img = false(size(I));
img(sub2ind(size(I), y, x)) = true;
imshow(img);
```

Here `x` and `y` denote the **column** and **row** coordinates, assuming they start at 1.  If `x` and `y` are **row** and **column** coordinates, simply swap the input parameters:

```
img = false(size(I));
img(sub2ind(size(I), x, y)) = true;
imshow(img);
```

Also, `I` is your image read in with `imread`.  As you want to have an image that is the same dimensions as `I`, we can certainly make use of that fact to create your output image.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to directly index into the matrix and set the locations to 1, then convert back to a `full` `logical` matrix:

```
img = sparse(y, x, true, size(I,1), size(I,2));
%img = sparse(x, y, true, size(I,1), size(I,2)); %// Use this if x is row and y is column
img = full(img);
imshow(img);
```

Comment: @user3859472 - My pleasure.   Please consider accepting one of our answers if you no longer need help.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you have not provided the intensities of the pixels, I assume you want to create a binary image which you can do easily as-

```
 img=[];
 for k=1:length(x) //assuming the length of x and y are same
     img(x(k),y(k))=1;
 end
 imshow(img);
```

Comment: hi, yes the output of the image i need in the binary format.  And I didn't get  why to assign 1 to img function

Comment: A binary image consists of '0' and '1'. I assume by your question that the coordinates in (x,y) are that of the location where the pixel is to be 1. So, I assigned 1 to `img` on all the coordinates specified by (x,y). PS: `img` is not a function, its just a simple matrix.

Comment: I agree this is the right way to do it. For efficiency, the variable img should be preallocated as: img = false(H,W), where H and W are the height and width of the final image. Also rather than writing 1 to the elements of img, the 'true' value should be written.

Comment: but how assigning 1 will get my image back? assigning 1 display nothing. I included two for loops.

Comment: before `imshow(img)`, do `img=img==1`. I think this will do!

Comment: @Gouda - There are more efficient ways to do this task, such as my answer shown here.  I'm inclined to disagree with the loop approach, but then again I've always been picky when it comes to loops.